# Update one flask sqlalchemy class affects the info added to another sqlalchemy class

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Background: I have two flask Sqlalchemy models which are:

```
class UltimaMediaCharacters(db.Model):
    #characterid=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    charactername=db.Column(db.PickleType,  unique=True, primary_key = True)    
    charactertype=db.Column(db.String(80), nullable = False)
    mediabookseriesname =db.Column(db.String(300), nullable = False)  
    mediatype=db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)    
    appearance = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)    
    biography=db.Column(db.String(900000000), nullable = False)  
    link = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable = False)
    characterrole = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable = True)
    characterside = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable = True) 
    read = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable = True)
class UltimaMediaBosses(db.Model):   
    bossname=db.Column(db.PickleType, primary_key = True)
    #charactername = db.Column(db.PickleType, db.ForeignKey('ultima_media_characters.charactername'))
    typeofboss=db.Column(db.String(80), nullable = False)
    mediacompanyandseriesname=db.Column(db.String(300), nullable = False)  
    mediatype=db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)    
    appearance = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)    
    role = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)
    side=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    biography=db.Column(db.String(900000000), nullable = False)  
    link = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable = False)
    read = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable = True)
```

And this python createboss function receives user input from HTML form and adds a data object to the UltimaMediaBosses model and UltimaMediaCharacters :

```
    def createboss():
        if request.form:
            bossname = request.form.get("bossname")           
            typeofboss = request.form.get("typeofboss")
            mediatype = request.form.get("mediatype")  
            appearance = request.form.getlist("appearance") 
            mediacompanyandseriesname = request.form.get("mediacompanyandseriesname")      
            role = request.form.getlist("role")
            side = request.form.get("side")
            biography= request.form.get("biography")
            link= request.form.get("link")
character = UltimaMediaCharacters(charactername=bossname,charactertype=typeofboss,mediatype=mediatype,mediabookseriesname=mediacompanyandseriesname,characterrole=role,characterside = side,appearance="['Shotclock of Destiny']",biography=biography,link=link,read=read)
                 db.session.add(character)
                 db.session.commit()
            
                
           
@app.route('/PXZ 3 Ultima Media: Characters/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
    def characterhomepage():#unit = db.session.query(UltimaUnits).all()
                characters = db.session.query(UltimaMediaCharacters).all()                    
                return render_template("Characters Index.html",characters=characters)
```

Problem: When I update information about a boss from UltimaMediaBosses model that was added to the UltimaMediaCharacters  model, the updated information won't show in the UltimaMediaCharacters  model on the index page called "Character Index.html" under characterhomepage() function. I also included the index code for character page(where the updated information would show).Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: There's too much code here, and the problem description is unclear.  Please try to trim it down to a [mre], and provide an example of some inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I made changes to the code and tried to explain problem as best as possible can

Comment: Is there any way I can actually talk to someone instead of communicating through comments?